# Delta-Epsilon Proofs

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the following limits using the delta-epsilon method. Can you help me out?

1.$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)}(3x^2y^2 + 4xy-12) = 120$$
2.$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+y^2} = 0$$

How do I work this out with the upper and lower boundaries?

Comment: For the first one, I would appeal to "product and sum of continuous functions is continuous". Else you may repeat the proof of that claim carefully with your particular functions. For the second one, I would use that $x^2$ is less than or equal to $(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: Choose (delta) = (epsilon/5) for the second problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

(2)

> $$ \Big|{5x^2y}\Big| \leq 5|x^2||y|\leq 5 (x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.  $$

**Note:**

> $$ |x|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad |y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to let my variables
go to $0$,
so,
in
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)}(3x^2y^2 + 4xy-12)$,
let
$x = 2+u$ and $y = 3+v$.

This expression becomes

$\begin{align}
3x^2y^2 + 4xy-12
&=3(2+u)^2(3+v)^2 + 4(2+u)(3+v)-12\\
&=3(4+4u+u^2)(9+6v+v^2) + 4(6+3u+2v+uv)-12\\
&= 3\cdot 4\cdot 9+12 + \text{ terms in }u\text{ and }v\\
&= 108+12 + \text{ terms in }u\text{ and }v\\
&= 120 + \text{ terms in }u\text{ and }v\\
\end{align}
$

so the limit as $u, v \to 0$
is $120$.

Note that you do not need to know
the exact ecpressions with $u$ and $v$
since they all go to $0$ with
$u$ and $v$.

Comment: How does this use a delta-epsilon proof?

Comment: A person, can do this without taking even this much pain , just plug in the numbers 2 and 3 for x and y. We can do this as the first function asked is continuous at the given point.

Answer (score 0):

My hint:

$$L=\lim_{(x,\: y)\to (0,\: 0)}\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,\: y)\to (0,\: 0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}.5x$$

Because: $$\left|\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\to L=0$$